# filter names that have previously been called so no need to be called again

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table:

| CustomerID | CustTrans |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | 2022-09-03 |
| C002 | 2022-09-02 |
| C003 | 2022-09-03 |
| C004 | 2022-09-02 |
| C002 | 2022-09-08 |
| C001 | 2022-09-05 |
| C002 | 2022-09-11 |
| C002 | 2022-09-23 |
| C004 | 2022-09-19 |
| C001 | 2022-09-18 |
| C003 | 2022-09-26 |
| C005 | 2022-09-17 |
| C006 | 2022-09-25 |
| C001 | 2022-09-25 |
| C005 | 2022-09-10 |

When I want to know who came on 2022/08/29 to 2022/09/04, and they also came on 2022/09/05 to 2022/09/11. I use a query:

```
select distinct CustomerID from trydata
where CustTrans between '2022-09-01' and '2022-09-04'
and CustomerID in (select distinct CustomerID from trydata
where CustTrans between '2022-09-05' and '2022-09-11')
```

The output: ***C001 C002***. But how to find attendees on 2022/08/29 to 2022/09/04 coming back on 2022/09/12 to 2022/09/18 but if that person has already come again on 2022/09/05 to 2022/09/11 then it doesn't need to be displayed?
((if look closely at the table above, **then there is no result (output must null or 0)**.
because c001 has been summoned before on September 5, 2022 to
September 11, 2022 while C005 cannot be summoned because they are not
present on August 29, 2022 to September 4, 2022))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to achieve this.

A sample query will look like this :

```
select distinct CustomerID 
from trydata a
where CustTrans between '2022-08-29' and '2022-09-04'
      and exists ( select 1 
               from trydata b
               where a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
                    and CustTrans between '2022-09-12' and '2022-09-18') 
      and not exists ( select 1 
               from trydata c
               where a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                    and CustTrans between '2022-09-05' and '2022-09-11')
```

Comment: if change it to, people who came at '2022-08-29' to '2022-09-04' and came again at '2022-09-19' to '2022-09-25'. then for not exist  query I use the time '2022-09-05' and '2022-09-18'. well, the results don't come out, even though if manually there is C004 that comes

Comment: i have just created a fiddle with your sample data and C004 does appear there with the specific date ranges. Please take a look here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b64e/10